# ZeroMQ to broadcast messages without centralized forwarder

Tags: tcp, zeromq, broadcasting

Is there a way of broadcasting messages in ZeroMQ without a centralized forwarder? The forwarder seems to me like a single point of failure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I asked the question in ZeroMQ's mailing list. Apparently, the best option is to deploy several forwarders and handle duplicates myself.